# iOS - How to display view or controller under UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I want to have a translucent navigation bar and display view or controller under it. Through the navigation bar, user can see the content display on the controller.But it always display from y=64 in iOS8. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: If you're using auto layout you should be able to set your view's top constraint to the top layout guide with a 0 pixel constant.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOption

//visible viewcontroller

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

//status bar

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

//One line pixel

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]];
```